# PL/SQL Commit Issue

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following code:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB (
job_name => 'MYJOB');
END;

COMMIT;
```

I get the following error message:

> Error report: ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "COMMIT" 
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

What is the problem with the syntax I am using for committing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be first `commit` and then `end` like below

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB (
job_name => 'MYJOB');
COMMIT;
END;
```

That's how Oracle documentation specify. If you are saying `commit` then `end` should go last. else just make it like

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB (
job_name => 'MYJOB');    
END;
/
```

see here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#ADMIN12401

Comment: Is this a property of committing an anonymous block? For example, what if I did something like "BEGIN...END; UPDATE...; COMMIT;"